Migrate Collapsing Toolbar from MaterialComponents to Material3
I a collapsing toolbar layout that I want to migrate to Material3 themes. I have reproduced the issue with a sample app I have built based on https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare. It looks like this (the way it should):

As soon as I change the parent theme to Material3, I get this:

This

is missing the title in the uncollapsed toolbar
is missing the whole toolbar after scrolling up

How can this be fixed?
Here is my layout:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="24dp">

            ...

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_discuss" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

my styles.xml:
<style name="Theme.DesignDemo" parent="Base.Theme.DesignDemo"></style>

<style name="Base.Theme.DesignDemo" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">#ff0000</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#00ffff</item>
    ... more colors ...
</style>

and my onCreate() implementation:
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail)

    val intent = intent
    val cheeseName = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_NAME)
    val toolbar: com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    // I tried adding this without effect
    // toolbar.title = cheeseName 


    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

    val collapsingToolbar: CollapsingToolbarLayout = findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar)
    collapsingToolbar.title = cheeseName

